# Getting stackoverflow on recursion

Tags: dart

I want to generate INSERT statement from JSON. The problem that I have problem with recursion (in section where I am getting nested elements). it's seems that I am getting SO.

```
import 'dart:convert';

main() {
  Map jsonMap = jsonDecode(
      '{"id":"1","name":"sample","Lots":[{"id":"1","title":"books","objs":[{"book":"name"}]}]}');

  KVToTableInsert(String tablename, Map jsonMap) {
    List<String> insertNoticeKeys = [];
    List<String> insertNoticeValues = [];
    jsonMap.forEach((key, value) {
      if (value is List) // nested
      {
        KVToTableInsert(key, jsonMap); // if comment this line all work
      } else {
        insertNoticeKeys.add(key);
        insertNoticeValues.add(value);
      }
    });

    String sql = "INSERT INTO $tablename (" +
        insertNoticeKeys.map((e) => '"$e"').join(', ') +
        ") VALUES (" +
        insertNoticeValues.map((e) => "'$e'").join(', ') +
        ")";
    print(sql);
  }

  KVToTableInsert("RootTable", jsonMap);
}
```

I expected to get 3 INSERT statment:

```
INSERT INTO RootTable ("id", "name") VALUES ('1', 'sample')
```

```
INSERT INTO Lots ("id", "title") VALUES ('1', 'books')
```

```
INSERT INTO Objs ("book") VALUES ('name')
```

But I am getting crush on this app.

Comment: I am not an expert in Dart, but I can see that you do not have a base case of recursion,  you have but you didn't call 'return' statement anywhere. Probably you call KVToTableInsert(key, jsonMap); so many times, and that is a reason for StackOverflowException

Comment: Yes, the problem is that you are calling `KVToTableInsert` with the same `jsonMap` which ends up making an infinite recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a slight problem in your code, basically in this part:

```
if (value is List){
  KVToTableInsert(key, jsonMap); // if comment this line all work
}
```

If you closely, take a look at your `KVToTableInsert`, you're passing arguments `Map` and not `list`. Which fails your recursion.

What you need to do is to pass the item of the array, into your `KVToTableInsert`, and this will work as expected

**FINAL SOLUTION**

```
// taking your jsonMap directly, and not decoding it
void main() {
  Map jsonMap = {
    "id":"1",
    "name":"sample",
    "Lots":[
      {
        "id": "1",
        "title":"books",
        "objs":[
          {
            "book":"name"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  };

  void KVToTableInsert(tablename, jsonMap){
    List<String> insertNoticeKeys = [];
    List<String> insertNoticeValues = [];
    jsonMap.forEach((key,value){
      if (value is List) 
      {
        // Here is the magic, you need to iterate over your list, and pass MAP, not LIST
        value.forEach((item){ KVToTableInsert(key, item);});
      } else {
        insertNoticeKeys.add(key);
        insertNoticeValues.add(value);
      }
    });
    
    String sql = "INSERT INTO $tablename (" +
        insertNoticeKeys.map((e) => '"$e"').join(', ') +
        ") VALUES (" +
        insertNoticeValues.map((e) => "'$e'").join(', ') +
        ")";
    print(sql);
  }
  
  KVToTableInsert("Rootable", jsonMap);
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
INSERT INTO objs ("book") VALUES ('name')
INSERT INTO Lots ("id", "title") VALUES ('1', 'books')
INSERT INTO Rootable ("id", "name") VALUES ('1', 'sample')
```

Also, look at the [Dart Programming Language Naming Conventions](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-408.pdf), it is a good practise to use `lowerCamelCase` for your function/method name.